# How to compute orthogonal vector in python?

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, linear-algebra

I have the following code to compute the orthogonal vectors of each vector coming as input from an  i,j dimension matrix. So each row in the matrix is a vector. Here is the code:

```
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
          for j in range(data.shape[1]):
              s=0 #row counter set to 0
              if j == data.shape[1]-1: #check if last row element has been reached
                  for k in range(j): #compute the sum of all previous values.
                      s=s+data2[i][k]*data[i][k]
                  data2[i][j] = -s/data[i][k]
              else:
                  data2[i][j] = random.uniform(1,random.getrandbits(10))
          dot(data[i],data2[i])
```

But it doesn't work as the dot function very rarely returns 0 which should be in case the vectors are orthogonal. I can't see a flow at the logic of my code. I simply fix j-1 random elements for the coefficients of the orthogonal vector and then in order to find the last coefficient i solve a simple equation which is the dot product of the previous coefficients of the random elements with the coefficients of the vector divided by the last coeffient. a1r1+a2r3+...+anrn=0. I know ai's. I fix random i-1 ri and then i solve the 1 var equation linear problem to find rn suth than ri vector would be orthogonal to a1 vector. The results from the last dot product computation i am getting are in this form:

```
===================================================
8.90285882653
===================================================
15.1275777619
===================================================
25.0847305913
===================================================
30.8608285102
===================================================
35.2496752739
===================================================
-53.3796252747
===================================================
16.302777
===================================================
29.3607765359
===================================================
-39.8982101139
===================================================
42.97222625
```

Comment: How big is the result of `dot`?  It's unlikely that with floating point numbers you'll get a result of *exactly* zero -- Usually you get numbers on the order of epsilon for your data type (`1e-16` for double precision).

Comment: I added the results in the question

Comment: The problem is that i don't even get a result close to 0

Comment: yep, those aren't even close :)  definitely a problem somewhere.  Now is the time I wish I remembered my linear algebra better ... :)

Comment: @mgilson i fixed the code a below but i am getting some weird results in between the 0s. So the dot product is not always 0. How that come?Can i force dot product to a specific precision suth that i am getting rid of this weird results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works. I edited a bit your code (got rid of the var s, which is now called quotient), but the only error was in the range of k up to the total length of the vector minus 2, and not up to the second to last one element. Notice in any case that this method is not robust.

```
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
      for j in range(data.shape[1]):
          if j == data.shape[1]-1: #check if last row element 
              quotient=(data2[i][:-1]*data[i][:-1]).sum()
              data2[i][j] = -quotient/data[i][-1]
          else:
              data2[i][j] = random.uniform(1)
      print dot(data[i],data2[i])
```

Comment: Now i am getting "better results" but still some inconsistencies: 0.0
0.0
-7.1054273576e-15
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
1.42108547152e-14
0.0
0.0
1.42108547152e-14
0.0
7.1054273576e-15
0.0
1.42108547152e-14
0.0
0.0
0.0
1.42108547152e-14
0.0

Comment: I can't get it very clearly. It depends on what whether or not i am getting a 0?Can i fix that ? For example why did i get  this -7.105...?

Comment: You mean that in 2013 computers you get an error in simple mathematics due to floats error in represention?I still can't get and i am quite impressed. And the errors i am getting are far away from 0...(?)

Comment: Also which one is a robust method?

Comment: @curious `-7.1054273576e-15` is the same as `0.0000000000000071054273576`, so the errors you are getting **are not** far away from 0.

Comment: @fleebol The *numpythonic* way of implementing your code, with no explicit Python loop, would be something like: `data2 = np.random.rand(*data.shape); quotients = np.sum(data2[:, :-1]*data[:, :-1], axis=1); data2[:, -1] = -quotients / data[:, -1]`. It should run much faster for larget data sets.

Comment: You can actually make it even faster, treating the multiply, then sum part as a dot product: `from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d; data2 = np.random.rand(*data.shape); quotients = inner1d(data2[:, :-1], data[:, :-1]); data2[:, -1] = -quotients / data[:, -1]`.

Comment: @Jaime But what about this value: 9.09494701773e-13. It's 9.09 * 10 **-13? From what it depends and i am getting every now and then not 0 values?

Comment: @curious It's floating point, it is inherently inexact when represented in base 10. If you can't live with a 1 in a trillion error, then use the decimal package, but be ready for a tremendous performance hit. Numpy has functions such as `np.allclose` to deal with this rounding errors in a convenient way.

Comment: @Jaime but is not 1 in a trillion it happends ~32 times per 173 dot product computations